# Dbus-Python for Windows

Tags: python-2.7, dbus

Can anyone tell me which is the best library for dbus python on window 7 32 bit? I am using the Python 2.7.

I download the latest zip for dbus-python and use it but it gives many imports errors like can not import dbus.exceptions and no module named _dbus_bindings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The zip archive that I downloaded from https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19049582/dbus.zip worked for me (originally linked from the article http://poquitopicante.blogspot.it/2012/07/building-dbus-python-on-windows-with.html)

1) You create a folder named "C:\dbus" and copy the folders "bin" and "etc" inside

2) Add "C:\dbus\bin" to the environment variable "Path"

3) Copy (merge) the 3 folders "lib\dbus-1.0", "lib\pkgconfig" and "lib\site-packages" in "C:\Python27\Lib"

That's all.